# Wordpress query for sticky posts that are scheduled

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, sticky

I am using the below query to show 4 most recent sticky posts in Wordpress.

```
<?php
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ); // Get all sticky posts
rsort( $sticky ); // Sort the stickies, latest first
$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 4 ); // Number of stickies to show
query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1 ) ); // The query

if (have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

ALL OF MY OUTPUTTED CODE GOES HERE - EDITED OUT TO SAVE SPACE

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php } else { echo ""; }?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This works great but if I have a scheduled sticky post (to appear at a future date), the query ignores it as one of the sticky posts and only shows 3 - not the 4 it should?

How can I modify below code to make sure no scheduled sticky posts show AND I still retain 4 slots for sticky posts?

UPDATED CODE BELOW SHOWS ALL POSTS - NOT JUST THE MOST RECENT 4 STICKY ONES.

```
<?php
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'post__in'  => $sticky,
'paged' => 1,
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);     

if (have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

ALL OF MY OUTPUTTED CODE GOES HERE - EDITED OUT TO SAVE SPACE

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php } else { echo ""; }?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit the number of posts you return in the query, not by slicing the array.

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post__in'  => $sticky,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
```

Take a look at the Codex reference above for examples of loops. Here's the gist of what you need.

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>'; 
} else {
    // no posts found
}

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Notice how the new WP_Query accepts the args from above. In the code you posted you weren't doing anything with them.

Comment: that now lists all of the sticky posts though. how do I limit it to most recent 4 only?

Comment: the posts_per_page argument should limit it to the most recent 4, are you doing something else that would change that?

Comment: just using your code as is. it worked as the array slice set to 4, but the posts_per_page has no effect. any ideas? thanks again for trying.

Comment: try adding `'paged' => 1` to the query

Comment: still no effect. What does have an effect is when I go to blog settings and change 'Blog Pages Show AT Most' amount. This seems to be messing with your code and its attempt to set posts_per_page to 4.

Comment: See my edit for a full example of the loop and how you need to use the `$args`.